# Highcharts Tooltip does not display utf-8 correctly

Tags: highcharts, utf-8

I built a map with european regions: [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/q539yzvh/1/)

this is my tooltip:

```
  tooltip: {
useHTML: true,
outside: false,
formatter: function() {

            return '<span>' + this.point.country + '<br>' + this.point.land + '<br>' + this.point.name + '<br>' + this.point.id + '<br>' + this.point.nuts + '<br>' + this.point.level + '<br>' + this.point.datum + '</span>';


                      }
        },
```

Unfortunately the tooltip does not dislay the utf-8 characters correctly. What can I do?
[image]

Comment: But _Türkei/Türkiye_ or _Grönland_  display correct…

Comment: I found the problem. The tooltip took the name column from the meta data of the geojson. Renaming the data column solved it.

Comment: @JohannesChrist Please write this answer in `Your Answer` field.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The tooltip took the name column from the meta data of the geojson. Renaming the data column solved it.